# how to pair values from python list

Tags: python, list, function

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
```

I would like to get a result of  below and store them in csv file. ( 6 rows total )

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
3,4
```

Is there a function to this or how can I accomplish and store this in csv file ?

Answer (score 7):

`itertools` is your friend...

http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(x, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: OP: use `'\n'.join(','.join(map(str, v)) for v in itertools.combinations(x, 2))` for desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Use [itertools.combinations](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). It's builtin in Python 2.6+.

```
import itertools

pairs = itertools.combinations(list, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and a list comprehension:

```
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in itertools.permutations(mylist, 2) if x < y]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

The condition `x < y` ensures you only get the permutations where `x` is lower than `y`.

The better option is to use `itertools.combinations(mylist, 2)`.

Comment: Why bother when itertools.combinations produces the desired result?

Comment: Why not use `combinations` then?

Comment: Yes, that's actually better.

Comment: If you're going for anti-golf, you can build `combinations` out of `product` before you build `permutations` out of `combinations`. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is simple enough to do it yourself:

```
l=[1,2,3,4]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    for j in range (i+1,len(l)):
        print l[i],l[j]
```

But solutions using `itertools` can be generalized much easier.